# REGEXP_COUNT and overlapping patterns

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a question about regular expressions. As stated in past questions I am working on semi-complete address parsing.

In the one area I am checking to see if there are too many directions present in the address. I am only checking for the shortened form so N,E,S,W,NE,NW,SE,SW. My current expression does work, but Im wanting something different to fit in better with the rest of the code.

```
REGEXP_LIKE(ADRS, '(^|\s)' || DIRN || '\s(|.+\s)' || DIRN || '(\s|$)', 'i')

DIRN = '(N|S|E|W|NW|NE|SE|SW)';
```

I want to use `REGEXP_COUNT(ADRS, '(\s|^)' || DIRN || '(\s|$)', 1, 'i')`

but I know it wont correctly count in a case like `"N E S W"`. As in this case the count will be 2. I know this is because the space between N and E is considered part of the N case, so it continues with "E S" and it doesnt consider E to be the start of the line and the space is already taken.

Now changing it to count all 4 is easy, but then it does not work for "North Albert S" as the count is 3 when I only want 1.

So is the type of expression I want possible? If it is what would it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle does not support `\b` for word boundary matches.

The simplest method is to replace every run of whitespace characters with a two space characters and then you can match using your regular expression:

```
REGEXP_COUNT(
  REGEXP_REPLACE( ADRS, '\s+', '  ' ),
  '(\s|^)' || DIRN || '(\s|$)',
  1,
  'i'
)
```

Comment: Would have been great if Oracle supported the boundaries, but this is a good work around.